# python settings.py on windows

Tags: python, django, git, bash

I am using Git Bash on windows 8, where I am trying to set up a new project in Django. I already installed both Python (ver. 3.4) and Django (1.7.4) and added a path to the environment variable in Windows like: C:\python34\scripts.

Once trying to create a project, I try to run settings.py command from within Shell like:

```
$settings.py
```

And receive the same errors again... Actually stacked with this already couple of days!

```
./settings.py: line 12: import: command not found
./settings.py: line 13: import: syntax error near unexpected token '('
./settings.py: line 13: 'BASE_DIR = os.pathdirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))'
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with `settings.py`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `/usr/bin/env python` etc.. in the file so you are trying to run it using bash hence the syntax errors, you would need to use `python settings.py` to actually run a python file. Using `chmod +x settings.py` will make it exectuable but bash cannot tell that `python` should be used to run it without the shebang line.

I am not overly familiar with django but I don't see how running `settings.py` is really useful it just contains the settings for the project. You would use either `manage.py` or `django-admin.py` from the command line.